# plays vs goes vs does

Tags: grammar

In the following sentences, when to use **plays** and when to use **goes** and when to use **does**:

He plays basketball

She plays volleyball

He plays football

She goes skiing

He goes ice skating

She goes roller skating

He does judo

She does athletics

Comment: *He **goes to** football on Sundays* could mean either as a ***player*** or as a ***spectator***. That same ambiguity applies with many if not *most* other "sports activities".

Comment: **Ice skating** isn't a game but an activity, so you "go ice skating." However **ice hockey** is a game, so you "play ice hockey".

Answer (score 1):

About playing different sports:
- to play basketball, football, volleyball, tennis, golf = that means they do that sport.

When a ball is involved, one usually uses the verb play.

- for athletics, judo, karates or other martial arts, the verb is do.
- John does karate but Mary does judo.

When the body is involved as the main idea, the verb do is used.

- for skiing, the verb ski is used.
- She skis every week.

When the body and an object is used for the sport, there is often a verb.

- **skiing** [you use skis]
- **surfing** [you use a surfboard], He surfs on Mondays.
- **snowboarding** [you use a snowboard]
- **parasailing** etc.

All the above refer to doing a particular sport. **That should not be confused with where a person has *gone or goes* in general.**
- Where's John? Answer: He's gone skiing for the day.
- Where's Mary? Answer: She's gone to her athletics practice.
- Where's Harry? Answer: He's gone skating. Or: He's skating at the rink.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your particular examples,

"Playing" can take the name of a game as its direct object.
"Goes" is used with gerunds (verb forms) describing activities which require leaving home to do.
"Does" is used with activities named by nouns, not gerunds derived from verbs.

These are observations; there may be exceptions.